# Moving elements and creating new ones dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fictional website which looks like the screenshot below. I want a dynamic element to it, for example when the **filter and search properties** link is clicked, the **agent preferences** link below it moves down the page and new items appear to give the user more options (maybe just a couple of extra buttons, or maybe a tickbox, etc) without the entire page reloading.

Is this possible using just HTML or is there always a javascript element to it? Also would the same be said about the semi-transparent 'pop-overs' ive seen on various websites? Im not particularly put off by Javascript, but would like to know how this is commonly achieved.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You will need to use javascript or jQuery (a javascript library).

Comment: @AlienArrays what an awesome collection on that site! I shall be investigating...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally whenever you want dynamic content, you'll have to use Javascript. With recent advancements in a lot of awesome web technologies (HTML5, CSS3, etc.), a lot of what you could only do in the past with other languages can be done, but you'll sacrifice compatibility (only the newer browsers will support these newer features).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have dynamic content with just Javascript, HTML and CSS, I've used the `function showHidden()` below to accomplish this.

[I've made a small demonstration with very minimal code to show you what you want in as few lines as possible](http://jsfiddle.net/dx3W6/)

If it's not intuitive, click "Click Me", and you'll see an element pop up.

You will notice that the element is already there, and is hiding until the button is pressed. This is one approach of doing it. Another one is appending to the list [like so](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

JQUery would be nice to have, you would be able to manipulate the DOM much more effectively with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extra elements to display when you click on the link, you can create this elements before and hide them with CSS `display: none;`. When you click the link, you call a JavaScript function (`onclick="myFunction();"`). The function should get the class of hidden elements with `document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass")`, loop over them with `for` loop and set them to `display: inline`.
With jQuery this is even easier. You can make `onclick="$('.yourClass').show();`.

For making things transparent, set CSS property `opacity: X;` where X is value between 0 and 1 (0 = fully invisible, 1 = fully opaque).

Here is a full example with HTML, CSS and JS:

```
<style>
.hidden {display: none;}
</style>

<button class="hidden">This is hidden for now</button>
<button onclick="$('.hidden').show();">This button will make the first button appear</button>
```

p.s.: you have to include jQuery library to make the above example work.

Answer (score -1):

The most simple way that I know of to achieve this is by using simple JS, to change the CSS  display property on click. I don't know of a way to achieve this on HTML alone, but to show you what I mean:

```
  <ul>
     <li onClick="viewOptions('furtherOptions')">Filter and Search Properties</li>
       <div id="furtherOptions" style="display: none">
         <ul>
            <li>Option</li>
         <ul>
        </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

In the HTML I would have the extra answers already coded out as if they were there, but with a CSS property of "display: none". Then you could do something like:

```
function viewOptions(varWhichOptions) {
   document.getElementByID(varWhichOptions).style.display = "block";
 }
```

Which will find the element who's id you passed it, and change it's CSS to block, in order to make it visible.

Of course, you would have to get more detailed for things like closing the one that is already expanded when you open a new one and so forth. To hide it again, you would do the same, but add "none" instead of "block".

Sorry, I know you said you wanted an HTML answer, but as I said, I am not aware of one.